# Deleting Parse Cloud Code JS File

Tags: parse-platform

I have several JS files that I reference from my `main.js` file in my Parse Cloud Code. Today I decided to delete one of the files. I removed all references to it from other JS files. But when I do `parse deploy` I get an error:

> Error: Failed to load helpers/addDurationToGraph.js with: Could not find file helpers/addDurationToGraph.js

If I add the file back and leave it empty, everything works fine.

How do I delete a Cloud Code file and not break deployment?

Comment: Do you see the error come from which file? There should be a message like "somefile.js:3"

Comment: Yes, and it references the old filename even after I update it on that line.